# unit testing of directive with default scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I am trying to unit test a directive which has default scope(scope:false) but I am not able to inject dependency of its controller.

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp',['MyDirectives','MyServices','MyControllers']);
```

Here is the directive

```
var MyDirectives = angular.module('MyDirectives', []);
MyDirectives.directive('myAddress', [ '$timeout', function ( $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) {
                return;
            }

            elm.on('focus', function () {
                scope.AppData.ShowSeparateAddress = false;
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is my controller

```
var  MyControllers = angular.module(' MyControllers', []);
MyControllers.controller('Step1', [
'$rootScope', '$scope', 'AppData', function ($rootScope, $scope, AppData) {
  $scope.AppData = AppData.get();
   }
```

Here is my App Service

```
var  MyServices = angular.module(' MyServices', []);
    MyServices.factory('AppData', [function () {
    var data;
    return {
        get: function () {
            data = data || {};
            return data;
        }
    };
   }]);
```

Here is the unit test for address directive

```
beforeEach(module(MyApp));


var element, compiledElement, directiveElement;
var scope, compile, ele,AppData,controller;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_){
scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
compile = _$compile_;
}));
 beforeEach(inject(function( _$controller_, _AppData_){

    AppData = _AppData_;
    controller = _$controller_('Step1',{scope:scope, AppData:AppData});
 }));
 function getCompiledElement(ele) {
     element = angular.element(ele);
     compiledElement = compile(element)(scope);
     scope.$digest();
     return compiledElement;
  }
it('should set show separate addrress as false when focussed',function(){
    ele = '<input type="text" data-my-address />';
    directiveElement = getCompiledElement(ele);
    console.log( directiveElement);
  expect( scope.AppData.ShowSeparateAddress ).toBe(false);
});
```

});
I get this following error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AppDataProvider <- AppData
```

I have  also trieed mocking the service through provide  but it did not work
Any help or idea ??

Comment: Does this actually work when running locally in the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure but: you have three arguments in your controller signature and you are passing only two. You should add the $rootScope

Comment: @mindparse yes above directive is  working fine. This directive is using default scope and also I am using AppData service inside the directive which is injected into its parent controller named 'Step1'.So I am not able to mock this AppData service in directive.

Comment: @Zakaria Do  I need to pass each and every arguments in my controller constructor for unit test. If I have large number of Dependencies in my controller then is it viable to pass all arguments? or should I pass arguments for which I need to unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You have three arguments in your controller signature and you are passing only two. You should add the `$rootScope` :

```
controller = _$controller_('Step1',{rootScope:scope, scope:scope, AppData:AppData});
```